# Android - SearchView top of ImageView not showing for API > 21

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, searchview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:translationZ="5dp">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="Book"
            android:src="@drawable/bookbackground"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            />
        <SearchView
            android:id="@+id/books"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Search Books"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:translationZ="5dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"

            />

    </RelativeLayout>




<!--https://pixabay.com/photos/books-students-library-university-1281581/ -->
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: try hiding the imageview and make sure the searchview is visible or not

Comment: Amod your searchview is there only...it just that it got hide ....try to set background to searchview you will surely get your searchview seen...or go for custom searchview so that it can seen

Comment: @Wini - background color solved the problem. Can you please add this as answer and i'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to set background to searchview you will surely get your searchview seen...
or go for custom searchview so that it can seen

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.4"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:translationZ="5dp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="Book"
        android:src="@drawable/bookbackground"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        />
    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/books"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Search Books"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:translationZ="5dp"
        android:background:"your color"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"

        />

</RelativeLayout>




  <!--https://pixabay.com/photos/books-students-library-university-1281581/ -->
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: need to have searchview on top of image

Comment: @AmodGokhale added

Answer (score 1):

I think you are doing little mistake you should define search view before image.

Answer (score 0):

Can you remove CenterInParent from SearchView

android:layout_centerInParent="true"

Comment: requirement to have it in center of image. Hence that tag is required